# How does the ELF64 loader know to update the initial addresses in .got.plt?

Tags: linux, elf, glibc

Consider the following program `hello.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("hello");
    return 0;
}
```

The file is compiled with `gcc -o hello -Og -g hello.c` and then loaded with `gdb hello`.

Inspecting the GOT for the call to `printf` with `p 'printf@got.plt'` gives

```
$1 = (<text from jump slot in .got.plt, no debug info>) 0x1036 <printf@plt+6>
```

which is the offset of the second instruction in the corresponding PLT entry relative to the start of the section.

After starting and linking the program with `starti`, `p 'printf@got.plt'` now gives

```
$2 = (<text from jump slot in .got.plt, no debug info>) 0x555555555036 <printf@plt+6>
```

which is the absolute address of the second instruction in the corresponding PLT entry.

I understand what is going on and why. My question is **how does the dynamic linker/loader know to update the section offset (0x1036) to the absolute address (0x555555555036)?**

A `p &'printf@got.plt'` before linking gives

```
$1 = (<text from jump slot in .got.plt, no debug info> *) 0x4018 <printf@got.plt>
```

and `readelf -r simple` shows a relocation entry for this address

```
Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x550 contains 1 entry:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000004018  000200000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 printf@GLIBC_2.2.5 + 0
```

But my reading of the [System V Application Binary Interface AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement](http://refspecs.linux-foundation.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.95.pdf), p.76, is that these relocation entries are only used when `LD_BIND_NOW` is non-null. Are there other relocation entries that I missed? What is the mechanism for rebasing offsets relative to the GOT's ultimate address?

Comment: After some more digging, it seems to me that the linker/loader does use the `R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO` relocation entries to rebase the offsets into the PLT when the segment containing `.plt.got` is loaded. The relevant source code seems to be in glibc at `elf/do-rel.h:elf_dynamic_do_Rel` and `sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h:elf_machine_lazy_rel`. As I don't completely understand the elf loader code, any expert confirmation of this would be welcome!

Comment: https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf explains it thoroughly, no answer can do a better job, probably.

Comment: Thanks @MaximEgorushkin. I read through the reference you suggest and I guess you're probably right. I've added an answer with everything I currently understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Drepper's [How To Write Shared Libraries](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), the dynamic linker relocates two kinds of dependencies:

1. *Relative relocations*: dependencies to locations within the same object. The linker simply adds the load address of the object to the offset to the target destination.
2. *Symbol relocations*: more complicated and expensive process based on a sophisticated symbol resolution algorithm.

For the PLT's GOT, Drepper states (§1.5.5) *At startup time the dynamic linker fills the GOT slot with the address pointing to the second instruction of the appropriate PLT entry.* A reading of the [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) source code suggests that the linker indeed loops through the `R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT` relocations (`elf/do-rel.h:elf_dynamic_do_Rel`) and increments the offsets they contain (`sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h:elf_machine_lazy_rel`):

```
if (__glibc_likely (r_type == R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT))
  {
    /* Prelink has been deprecated.  */
    if (__glibc_likely (map->l_mach.plt == 0))
      *reloc_addr += l_addr;
    else
      ...
```

when lazy PLT binding is used (the default case).